# How to automatically merge on upload

Tags: linux, version-control, upload, merge, compare

I am searching for a solution to automatically merge files on upload.

To be more precise, we are working in small groups doing web-development, working on the same folder on our Debian Server remotely, so the Problem is of course that if we often have the situation, where up to 3 People need to write in the same php file, at the moment we are trying to coordinate when which person is allowed to work on it.

So my idea was if there is a subversion like solution, to just merge every time we save the file via sshfs.

Comment: Why not use a proper version control system?

Comment: thanks, but I already tried to mange this with subversion, but the workflow is horrible when doing a lot of small changes via eclipse, also I do not need a complete version history, just the merge functionality

Comment: Don't use `subversion`, it's a tool of the past, use `mercurial` or `git`, i've even read good things about `bazaar` and `darcs`

Comment: @user1403333 subversion is difficult when merging. I have used git with github, and can recommend that. Automatic merging is difficult if there is no history, thus an adequate solution for your problem will require some form of version control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use version control.  Here are some options.  Which one you should use depends on a variety of factors.

- [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)
- [Git](http://git-scm.com/)
- [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

You can then have the server your site is on pull from the repository.